# Transformation question

Tags: geometry, transformation

My question is :

> If a figure on a coordinate system is dilated, find the line of reflection between the figure and the dilated figure

How can I get the answer?
Is there an algebraic method? 
I hope you can help.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In your question, you should indicate what you've tried and where you are stuck. If you don't do this and just ask for solutions, your question is likely to get downvoted and closed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation